# DbSet.attach() made next query return wrong result

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.2

Let's say this `User` data has been recorded in the database..

```
User {
   Id = 1,
   Name = "John",
   Job = "Programmer"
};
```

And later on, I want to update his name. so, I execute this command

```
var entity = new User { Id = 1 };

_context.Users.Attach(entity);

entity.Name = "Jack";

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Finally, in I query again to see update

```
var order = await _context.Users
                          .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == 1));
```

But the data I got is weird...

```
User {
   Id = 1,
   Name = "Jack",
   Job = null <----- this should not be null
};
```

it looks like query result is come from when `_context` has been tracked the record after `attach()` method was called.

Any, idea or what should I do to prevent this weird result.

Comment: why shouldn't it? you just modified the user to be a new user with job set to null. If you want to update certain properties of the existing user, you should retrieve it first.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro, but the data in the database is updated correctly. no value is missing include "Job" field.

Comment: that is weird. Then most likely only the altered properties are actually marked as modified instead of the whole entity. I'd advise to only attach full entities to the context. If you are willing to go forward with this approach, you can either detach the object from the context or open a new context for retrieval.

Comment: @JongzPuangput What happens if you execute `_context.Users.Where(u=>u.Id==1);`? Does it return you more than 1 records?

Comment: Because EF Core will return entity instance from the memory if such exists. In your case instance for `Id = 1` already exists/tracked in DbContext and which will be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are seeing #null for the job is because the entity the DbContext returned you on the final query would have been the instance you initiated and attached to the context.  When you call SaveChanges with your entity, it had an ID of 1, Name of "Jack" and a Job of #null. The tracking told EF only the name had changed, so that is all that went to the DB in the Update statement.

EF does some slightly dubious stuff behind the scenes, but when you fetch an entity it will return whatever it has in the cache if available before loading an entity from the database. What can be confusing about that is that if you are profiling against the DB you will see a `SELECT` raised against the database, but the entity returned will reflect the last cached state, not the database State.  To refresh the entity you can either:

```
_context.Entity(user).Reload();
```

to reload the entity being tracked. or ...

```
_context.Entity(user).EntityState = EntityState.Detached;
user = _context.Users.Single(x => x.Id == 1);
```

... to detach the entity you updated again to force EF to reload when asked or ...

```
user = _context.Users.AsNoTracking().Single(x => x.Id == 1);
```

... load a fresh untracked reference.

As a general rule, when editing entities you should load the entity, apply the changes, and save rather than the Id + `Attach` trick. Id + `Attach` is a handy hack for delete scenarios or possibly bulk updates, but only within short-lived DbContexts so that these tracked "partial" entities don't get returned again by other queries.